# Why motion layout onSwipe, does not work?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using motion layout and when I set on swipe to image view it does not work.
I have two transition. the first transition is for recycler view and I set on swipe for that and it working

this is my code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <MotionScene 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/image_start" />

   <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/image_end">
      <Constraint
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mainRv" />

     <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:alpha="0" />
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/image_start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/image_end" >
    <KeyFrameSet>
    </KeyFrameSet>
    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/mainRv"/>
</Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

and I used this transition. but does not work

```
    <Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/image_start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/image_end" >
    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/mainRv"
        motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />
    </Transition>
```

[this is my motion layout graph (end transition has problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzeWA.png)

Note : transition time line does working correctly.

[this is start position picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pynd.png)
[this is end position picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE6mg.png) (recycler view dragged down)

Answer (score 0):

First always set your start constraint because it cause some bugs in some devices. And to fix your issue play with direction and touch side and test it. Set dragUp and top and other cases.

Comment: the start constraint of first transition is empty but it work's.